# Powerapps - get stuck with UpdateContext

Tags: datetime, powerapps

I am trying to build a PowerApp to log setup times of our machines by our fitters.

This is what my app looks like:

[image: Main Page]

There are buttons named "Uhrzeit". Pressing these will write the current date and time into the Date/Time fields. I am using the following code:

```
UpdateContext({Total8:(Text( Now(); "[$-de-DE]dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss" ))})
```

The Date/Time field is named Total8.

The code is working well but after saving the form and opening a new record the old data is still available in the fields. By clicking on the button "Zeiten zurücksetzen" I can "delete" the old data.

```
UpdateContext({Total8:""})
```

Problem: When I open one of the older records the old data is not available in the form. There is only the value of the last record. In the Common Data Service where my records are saved the values are correct.

As an example, I am saving this record:

[image: Record_1]

When I open a new record, the values of the record 1 are still available. This should not be the case if my app worked properly.

For your Information:
If I enter the date/time without tapping the button, saving the record and opening a new record I don't have the problem. I think the "UpdateContext" code is not the code I should use here.

Can anyone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a problem with using the contexts in this way -- but remember that a context is just a variable.  It isn't automatically linked to a datasource in any special way - so if you set it equal to Now(), it's going to keep that value until you do something different.

When you view an old record, you need to get the data from CDS and update your contexts to match the CDS data.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats my problem.

I want the variable to be linked to a datasource. Or is it possible to write the date/time into the fields without using a context variable?